# AutoRaise (bring window to front) - XQuartz

Tags: window-manager, automation, x11, xquartz, macos

I'd like focus-follows-mouse (autoraise) with XQuartz windows (for X-Forwarding purposes).

I'm using a small app posted on SO on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073462/2550349) and it works OK for regular apps (which run under Quartz, I assume).

For any X-Forwarded X11 apps however, it's not supported. Using amethyst focus-follows-mouse feature it's also not supported. I think I've read XQuartz is hard to add support to, for stuff like this, but that's all I know.

I've read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39204/script-to-raise-a-single-window-to-the-front#39216) that you can raise a window with `open`. I've tested with firefox `open -a firefox` and it works OK. I tried `open -a xquartz` and I get the following:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app with error -10810.
```

I've tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181031/256131) for the issue but it didn't work. I'm not sure what it even means or where to search about it.

Can anybody help me out on how to come up with a scriptable way to raise an XQuartz window?